# Difficulty with simulating clicks in Selenium and then scraping data of new page after click

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to simulate a click from this page (http://www.oddsportal.com/baseball/usa/mlb/results/) to the last page number found at the bottom.  The click I use on the icon in my code seems to work, but I can't get it to scrape the actual page data I want to after simulating this click.  Instead, it just scrapes the data from the first original url.  Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url='http://www.oddsportal.com/baseball/usa/mlb/results/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get(url)

timeout=5

while True:
    try:
        element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, '»|'))
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)

        last_page_link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('»|')
        last_page_link.click()


        element_present2 = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ".//th[@class='first2 tl']"))
        WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present2)

        content=driver.page_source

        soup=BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')

        dates2 = soup.find_all('th',{'class':'first2'})
        dates2 = [element.text for element in dates2]
        dates2=dates2[1:]

        driver.quit()
    except TimeoutException:
        print('Timeout Error!')
        driver.quit()
        continue
    break
print(dates2)
```

Comment: Try to remove this line `driver.get(driver.current_url)` as it seem to be redundant

Comment: Hi, just tried that and it is still giving me the same dates from the original url

Comment: your indentation is wrong.. you need to fix because they are syntax errors

Comment: thanks for pointing that out @CoreyGoldberg, I have updated my code.